What is the best way to find a nested directory inside another directory in Python?
I have a requirement to find a nested hierarchy of directory inside a base directory structure.
Lets say my base directory in which I want to find is : /home/user/my_base_dir
And the directory that I want to find inside it is : log_dir
I have written tried below code which is working:
import glob
import os

base_dir = "/home/user/my_base_dir"
to_find  = base_dir + "/*/log_dir"

for dir_path in filter (os.path.exists, glob.iglob(to_find)):
    print ("Found = ", dir_path)

The problem with this is , in this case I am assuming that it will be available underneath one directory level (which is the *) as :  */log_dir
But what is the way to find it under any nested hierarchy of the base_dir for which I do not know how to build the regex.
Thanks
